# How can I link my Web Scraper in JavaScript and layout in HTML + CSS to work together?

Tags: javascript, html

I am fairly new to JavaScript and coding in general so excuse my ignorance, please. I am trying to achieve a user input form that will act as a search bar for just images found via a Google image search.

I am specifically asking about passing the keyword that is inputted by the user to the scrapeSite() function. I have tried a few ways to achieve this but this made the most sense to me. The user input outputting to the paragraph element works alone. The web scraper works alone. However, when I try to pass the input to the scraping function I am given an error.

The error is as follows:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Cannot access 'axios' before initialization
> at scrapeSite (web-scraper.js:13:19)
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (web-scraper.html:37:40)

Here you may find the user input with the onClick event.

```
<div class="title"><h1>Web Scraper Demo</h1></div>
      <div class="ws-userinput">
        <p>Please provide search terms for the following prompt in order to scrape for the image required.</p>
        Enter something in the box: <br>
        <input type="text" id="myText">
        <button onclick="scrapeSite()">Click me</button>
        <p id="log"></p>
      </div>
```

Web Scraper - this outputs an array of images based on the keyword search results.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');  // new addition

async function scrapeSite() {
    var keyword = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = keyword
    const url = `https://www.google.com/search?gl=us&q=${keyword}&tbm=isch`;
    const { data } = await axios.get(url);
    
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);

    const results = [];
    $('table.RntSmf').each((i, elem) => {
        const imgSrc = $(elem).find('img').attr('src');
        results.push({ imgSrc});
    });

    return results;
}

scrapeSite(keyword).then(result => {
        console.log(result)
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I am not very knowledgeable regarding Node.js, do I have to create a server in order to connect the two? I am unsure why I am getting this error, everything I look up about it says that I have variables out of scope, I tried moving the 'variables' within the function, and that gave an error as well. I feel stuck, I would appreciate any help

Comment: I believe you need to add more details to the question, for example how is your project setup, since `require` does not work in browser directly without you need to do that using third party libraries like `webpack` . The error clearly says `axios` is not defined because it's not loaded... try using `fetch` instead which is natively available in browsers.

Comment: @Manish I am not quite sure what further information needs to be provided, could you clarify for me? I set up a node.js project and ran the JavaScript file of the code I provided and it outputted an array. Sorry if I am not being very clear, I am pretty new to this.

I appreciate your suggestion of fetch, could you clarify replacing fetch with what? The call for the axios api?

Comment: Yeah, replace axios with `fetch` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch . More details like Are you using webpack? Are you using any framework or just plain HTML, JavaScript?

Comment: @Manish I will try this thank you! No framework just plain HTML and JavaScript.